# Can TeX read a line in a file and use it as input?

Tags: input

Yes, TeX can read a line in a file and use it as input. The example working code below now implements the accepted answer from Willie Wong.
For the new user: "\inputL" and "\inputR" are not TeX commands. Mr. Wong's answer states that they are macros.
A TeX macro is something like a variable that is declared when the macro name is first used, and a string value is read into it. It is something like a function because when the macro name is used a second time, when it will return the string value.
Source files, desired output, and example code follow.

Please assume source files with these contents.

LeftPageParagraphs.tex:

```
This is paragraph 1 from LeftPageParagraphs.tex file.

This is paragraph 2 from LeftPageParagraphs.tex file.
```

RightPageParagraphs.tex:

```
This is paragraph 1 from RightPageParagraphs.tex file.

This is paragraph 2 from RightPageParagraphs.tex file.
```

Desired output document should have a left page and a right page.

Left page should have read and input one paragraph:

```
This is paragraph 1 from LeftPageParagraphs.tex file.
```

Right page should have read and input one paragraph:

```
This is paragraph 1 from RightPageParagraphs.tex file.
```

An annotated minimum working example of the solution:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{paracol} % Parallel columns package

% The \chunks command outputs a pair of parallel paragraphs to 
% the left and right columns on facing pages.
\newcommand\chunks[2]{%
    \begin{leftcolumn*}
        {#1}%
    \end{leftcolumn*}%
    \begin{rightcolumn}
        {#2}%
    \end{rightcolumn}%
}

\begin{document}

%  Open *.tex files in input streams 0 and 1).
\openin0 = {LeftPageParagraphs}
\openin1 = {RightPageParagraphs}

\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}     % Open parallel columns "environment".
    
    \read0 to \inputL  % <-- Reads first line from first file.
    \read1 to \inputR  % <-- Reads first line from second file. 
        
    \chunks            % <-- Pass: Adds line from each file as paragraph.
        {\inputL}  
        {\inputR}  

\end{paracol}

% Close files (input streams 0 and 1).
\closein0
\closein1

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, you're using primitive TeX commands? Where are you finding the documentation? TeXbook? If not, it's not "the documentation". (although TeX by Topic is also pretty good)

Comment: Do you happen to have shell-escaped enabled or LuaTeX? Programming in Lua is way more convenient.

Comment: https://latexref.xyz/_005cread.html suggests you would want first `\read0 to \inputL` followed by `\read1 to \inputR` and then call  `\chunks{\inputL}{\inputR}`. (I haven't tested it since there were no `Chapter01Left` and `...Right` files provided for testing.)

Comment: reading a file is easy.  The tricky part is if the file you're reading isn't actually tex input.  What does your file look like?

Comment: `\read0 to \input ` would redefine the command `\input` making it impossible to `\input{myfile}` also don't use stream numbers directly, always use `\newread` to allocate a number for your use.

Comment: 1. I would be happy to use "non-primitive" commands to open and read a file if I knew what they were. Documentation used: TeX by Topic (online); TeX Companion (4th ed.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Can anyone show me a small working code example? My test source files are simple text, one "paragraph" per line: "Abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde". I can't find a way to upload files to StackExchange. The documentation was indeed online TeX By Topic. I have on hand: Guide to LaTeX (4th ed.) by Kopka and Daly and LaTeX Companion (2nd ed.) by Mittlebach and Goossens.

Comment: Willy Wong: This code will not compile in TeXStudio: 
 read0 to \inputL 
 read1 to \inputR
 \chunks
  {\inputL}
  {\inputR}

Comment: @CaslonMelior: what's the error message? I just threw together a basic testing example and it works.

Comment: @CaslonMelior There's expl3 and Lua and e.g. PythonTeX. Expl3 can be used if you're using LaTeX and not plain TeX. By the way, read [How do comment @​replies work? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Although TeX by topic is pretty good. The other option is reading example code of the people on the site.

Comment: @WillyWong Dear Mr. Wong: My error. Your suggested code worked for the first paragraph on the left and right facing pages. However, repeating the code to get the second paragraph fails.

Comment: @WillyWong Dear Mr. Wong: 
 %  Open files.
 \openin0 = {LeftPageParagraphs}
 \openin1 = {RightPageParagraphs}
 
 \begin{paracol}[1]*{2}

  \read0 to \inputL
  \read1 to \inputR  
  
  \chunks            % <-- Pass: Adds paragraph.
   {\inputL}  
   {\inputR}  

  \read0 to \inputL
  \read1 to \inputR  
  
  \chunks            % <-- Fail: No second paragraph.
   {\inputL}  
   {\inputR} 
  
 \end{paracol}
 
 % Close files.
 \closein0
 \closein1

Comment: Isn't that expected behavior? Your file has a blank line, so you get a blank line.

Comment: @user202729 Some TeX documentation specifies a blank line to indicate the end of a paragraph, equivalent to issuing the \par command at the end of a paragraph. I will try removing the the blank line in the source text files and see if it works.

Comment: @user202729 Removing the blank line worked. Thank you for the suggestion! I sure would like to know why we are told to use blank lines for paragraphs (works with \include and \input of files) BUT NOT when opening a file and reading it line by line. This seems inconsistent.

Comment: @CaslonMelior: (a) if you want to use the comment-notify function of this website, make sure to type the usernames correctly. (b) I am getting the feeling that you are trying to re-invent the wheel. Take a look at the `reledmac` bundle, and specifically the `reledpar` package https://ctan.org/pkg/reledpar . One of its functions is for you to have two streams of texts for the left/right sides and align the paragraphs between the two sides appropriately; I suspect this is close to what you want?

Comment: (The `reledpar` documentation can be a bit hard to parse; take a look also at the relevant examples in https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples (search for reledpar, there are dozens.))

Comment: @CaslonMelior TeXbytopic says that it reads a line, not a paragraph. So nothing inconsistent here.

Comment: @WillieWong I am sorry I misspelled your name. I used what popped up after I typed @. I assumed that StackOverflow was providing the correct name. If it is still wrong, please tell me how I should properly spell your name.

Comment: @WillieWong
   Thank you for the suggestions. Before starting with the paracol package, I looked at the documentation for the parallel and reledpar packages. reledpar looked great, but it requires using line numbers if you want to have footnotes. I don't want line numbers and I do need footnotes.
   In my first project in TeX, I am proceeding by small logical steps. Once a thing works, I try the next thing.

Comment: @WillieWong Your comment is the correct answer. A moderator said I should write to you and request that you turn your comment into an answer. It's the one that starts "suggests you would want first \read0 to \inputL followed by \read1 to \inputR" and ends with your name. You can see that I changed my example code to use your solution. It was certainly better than having to learn entire new languages to get TeX to do something! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Converted from comment*)

The command `\read<stream> to<macro>` stores the next line of input from `<stream>` and stores it as `<macro>`.

So if the file you are reading starts

```
Hello World!
Hi There.
```

Then

```
\read0 to\InPutWorld
\read0 to\InPutThere
```

will have the same effect as

```
\def\InPutWorld{Hello World!}
\def\InPutThere{Hi There.}
```

---

Hence, to accomplish what you want, you probably should:

```
\read0 to \inputL
\read1 to \inputR 
\chunks{\inputL}{\inputR}
```